# Drawing qqline in the Chi- Square QQ plot in R

Tags: r, plot, quantile

I copy the following code the `r help`. However, the `qqline` function is not working. What is the reason?

```
library(mgcViz)
y <- rchisq(500, df = 3)
## Q-Q plot for Chi^2 data against true theoretical distribution:
qqplot(qchisq(ppoints(500), df = 3), y, main = expression("Q-Q plot for" ~~ {chi^2}[nu == 3]))
qqline(y, distribution = function(p) qchisq(p, df = 3), prob = c(0.1, 0.6), col = 2)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the qqline with `mgcViz` you need to use ggplot:

```
library(mgcViz)
y <- rchisq(500, df = 3)
## Q-Q plot for Chi^2 data against true theoretical distribution:
qqplot(qchisq(ppoints(500), df = 3), y, main = expression("Q-Q plot for" ~~ {chi^2}[nu == 3]))

# Add qq line
library(ggplot2)
ggplot2::last_plot() + qqline(y, distribution = function(p) qchisq(p, df = 3), prob = c(0.1, 0.6), col = 2)
```

[image: qq plot]

To view the intercept and slope of your qqline, you can do the following:

```
my.qqline = qqline(y, distribution = function(p) qchisq(p, df = 3), prob = c(0.1, 0.6), col = 2)
> my.qqline$data
   intercept     slope
1 0.08606285 0.9290453
```

Comment: @score324 :It's almost a `45` degree line. I have added some code that shows you the way to get the slope and intercept of the qq-line. We see that the slope of this qq-line is 0.929 and a `45` degree line would have a slope of 1.

Comment: Yes thanks, `ggplot2::last_plot() + geom_abline(slope=1, intercept=0)`

Comment: @score324 : great, glad that you figured it out. If you found my answer useful, please consider marking it as correct and upvoting please? Thanks :)